# what is Keys.ZENKAKU_HANKAKU in webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver

As i came across this code,

```
 driver.findElement(By.name("xxx")).sendKeys(
                Keys.ZENKAKU_HANKAKU);
```

so wanted to know why and when to use this kind of key.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a Japanese modifier key which will change between Hankaku (half-width) and Zenkaku (full-width) characters.  To try and visualise this:

Hankaku - `12345`

Zenkaku - `1 2 3 4 5`

As to which key it is bound to on the keyboard, F9 and F10 are common bindings.  F10 will change from Zenkaku to Hankaku, and F9 from Hankaku to Zenkaku.

Source - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_input_keys#Half-width.2FFull-width_.28.E5.8D.8A.E8.A7.92.2F.E5.85.A8.E8.A7.92.29)